# ошибка TypeError: string indices must be integers, при запуске скрипта python на хероку

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
url_list = [
{'city': 1, 'language': 2, 'url_data': {'hh': 'https://hh.ru/search/vacancyarea=1&fromSearchLine=true&st=searchVacancy&text=JavaScript', 'superjob': 'https://www.superjob.ru/vacancy/search/?keywords=JavaScript&geo%5Bt%5D%5B0%5D=4', 'habr_job': 'https://career.habr.com/vacancies?city_id=678&q=JavaScript&type=all'}},
{'city': 1, 'language': 3, 'url_data': {'hh': 'https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?clusters=true&area=1&enable_snippets=true&salary=&st=searchVacancy&text=Java&customDomain=1', 'superjob': 'https://www.superjob.ru/vacancy/search/?keywords=Java&geo%5Bt%5D%5B0%5D=4&click_from=facet', 'habr_job': 'https://career.habr.com/vacancies?city_id=678&q=Java&type=all'}}, 
{'city': 1, 'language': 1, 'url_data': {'hh': 'https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=1&fromSearchLine=true&st=searchVacancy&text=Python&from=suggest_post', 'superjob': 'https://www.superjob.ru/vacancy/search/?keywords=Python&geo%5Bt%5D%5B0%5D=4', 'habr_job': 'https://career.habr.com/vacancies?city_id=678&page=1&skills[]=446&type=all'}}
]

parsers = (
    (hh, 'hh'),
    (superjob, 'superjob'),
    (habr_job, 'habr_job')
)

jobs, errors = [], []

for data in url_list:
    for func, key in parsers:
        url = data['url_data'][key]
        j, e = func(url, city=data['city'], language=data['language'])
        jobs += j
        errors += e
```

url = data['url_data'][key]  Здесь происходит ошибка TypeError: string indices must be integers
функции из parsers не выкладывал сюда, т.к не имеют отношения к проблемe
Ошибка возникает только при запуске на хероку, когда запускаю локально - ошибка отсутствует.

Comment: У меня на первой же строке ошибку выдаёт, нельзя просто так данные в питоне через строчку после равно сразу переносить. У вас там точно именно такой код на сервере?

Comment: Кроме этого кода, есть еще 3 функции hh, supejob, habr_job. Перенос после знака  = поправил.

Comment: Там нету никакой ошибки